Second class currents
If we consider the most general form of the matrix elements (vector part) associated with a charged current neutrino-nucleon interaction at low energy, it is given by
$$
\begin{equation}
\left\langle p\left(p_p\right)\left|v_W^\rho(0)\right| n\left(p_n\right)\right\rangle=\overline{u_p}\left(p_p\right)\left[\gamma^\rho F_1\left(Q^2\right)+\frac{i \sigma^{\rho \eta} q_\eta}{2 m_N} F_2\left(Q^2\right)+\frac{q^\rho}{m_N} F_3\left(Q^2\right)\right] u_n\left(p_n\right)
\end{equation}
$$
However, in the book Neutrino Physics and Astrophysics by Giunti, it is stated that the second class current $F_3$ is zero because it must satisfy
$$
\begin{equation}
\left\langle p\left(p_p\right)\left|v_W^\rho(0)\right| n\left(p_n\right)\right\rangle=\left\langle p\left(p_n\right)\left|v_W^\rho(0)\right| n\left(p_p\right)\right\rangle^*
\end{equation}
$$
However, I do not see a way to demonstrate that this is indeed the case based on that property. Thank you!
About notation: $p_(p,n)$ is the 4-moment of proton,neutron.

Donoghue & Holstein.

Linked.
